# Magento 2 Product Sort by Price as High to low

Tags: magento2, product, price, sort

I set default sort by price in admin
but still i need to sort price from high to low.
Magento by default sort it low to high.
i try to find option in admin but can't find that.
can any one tell me code for that to make it high to low sort by default?
I am using porto theme for my store.

Comment: Not working for magento 2.2.5,

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/137131)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/137131)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/137131)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For invert your result from ASC to Desc at load time.
Simply add this code in your extended Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml

```
<body>
    ...
    <referenceContainer name="content">
       <referenceBlock class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="category.products.list" as="product_list">
            <action method="setDefaultDirection">
                <argument name="dir" xsi:type="string">desc</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </referenceContainer>
    ...
</body>
```

Comment: I got these issues
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'referenceBlock', attribute 'class': The attribute 'class' is not allowed.
Line: 919
Element 'referenceBlock', attribute 'as': The attribute 'as' is not allowed.

Comment: Thank you much.
My Solution: Delete Attribute "class" and "as" in /vendor/creativestyle/frontend-extension/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml and it works so far without side effect :)

Comment: Worked flawlessly with the athlete2 theme, I just added this block at the top of the body section. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Copy the file `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml` to your theme i.e; `app/design/frontend/{{Namespace}}/{{Theme}}/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml`.

And place the following code into the XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <referenceBlock class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="category.products.list" as="product_list">
                <action method="setDefaultDirection">
                    <argument name="dir" xsi:type="string">desc</argument>
                </action>
            </referenceBlock>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 1):

You must have to override the **getAvailableOrder()** and **setCollection()** function of the Magento

> /vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/ProductList/Toolbar.php

Below is the code which may help you.

```
public function aroundGetAvailableOrders(\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $subject, \Closure $proceed)
{
    $returnValue = $proceed();
    unset($returnValue['price']);
    $returnValue['priceDesc'] = 'price - high to low';
    $returnValue['priceAsc'] = 'price - low to high';
    return $returnValue;
}

public function aroundSetCollection(\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $subject, \Closure $proceed, $collection)
{
    $returnValue = $proceed($collection);
    if ($subject->getCurrentOrder() == 'priceHighToLow') {
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')->setOrder('price', 'ASC');
        $collection->load();
    }
    return $collection;
}
```